# finiteness of moments of the stationary distribution of a Markov chain

Tags: pr.probability, ergodic-theory, markov-chains

I have a Markov chain $\{X_k\}_{k\geq 0}$ on $\mathbb{R}$. The corresponding probability density functions satisfy
$$
f_{k+1}(t) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \Psi(t,\tau)f_k(\tau)\,d\tau,\qquad k=0,1,2,\dots
$$
I have an analytic expression for the transition kernel $\Psi$, and let's suppose for the moment that the Markov chain is irreducible, positive recurrent, aperiodic, and Harris. And of course, $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \Psi(t,\tau)\,dt=1$.

I am interested in characterizing the moments of the stationary distribution $\pi$. Specifically:

- What are sufficient conditions that would ensure the moments of $\pi$ are finite?
- Is there a way to compute bounds on the moments of $\pi$ if they are finite? I can't do this numerically because $\Psi$ is parameterized; I'm interested in how the moments of $\pi$ vary as a function of these parameters. My first instinct was to try to write $\int_{-\infty}^\infty t^mf_{k+1}(t)\,dt$, substitute the recurrence from above and try to simplify and maybe use Holder's inequality, but I ran into a roadblock: it turns out that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty t^m \Psi(t,\tau)\,dt = \infty$ for all $m\geq 1$, even though the integral is finite for $m=0$. So at this point I have no idea how to proceed.

Comment: If your transition probabilities don't have finite moments, why would you expect $\pi$ to have finite moments?

Comment: Now that I think of it, I guess that doesn't make much sense... My numerical simulations suggested that $\pi$ exists and has finite moments, but you bring up a good point. I will have to think about this more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote:

> I can verify that $\Psi$ is continuously differentiable,
> $\Psi(t,\tau)>0$ for all $t,\tau\in\mathbb{R}$, and of course, $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \Psi(t,\tau)\,dt=1$.
>
> [...] these properties should be sufficient to
> guarantee that a stationary distribution $\pi$ exists and is unique,
> and that $f_k \to \pi$ (in the T.V. sense) for any initial $f_0$.

Of course, this is not so. E.g., if $\Psi(t,s)=g(t-s)$, where $g$ is the standard normal pdf, then (considering, for instance the Fourier transform, one can easily see that) there is no stationary distribution. Also, then for any initial $f_0$ and each real $t$ we have $f_k(t)\to0$ as $k\to\infty$.

---

You have now added more conditions:

> let's suppose for the moment that the Markov chain is irreducible,
> positive recurrent, aperiodic, and Harris. And of course,
> $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \Psi(t,\tau)\,dt=1$

saying then the following:

> These properties should be sufficient to guarantee that a stationary
> distribution $\pi$ exists and is unique, and that $f_k \to \pi$ (in
> the T.V. sense) for any initial $f_0$. Moreover, all moments of $\pi$
> are finite and the $m^\text{th}$ moment of $f_k$ converges to the
> $m^\text{th}$ moment of $\pi$ as $k\to\infty$.

However, the latter conclusion will still fail to hold in general -- because the the state space of the chain can be nonlinearly transformed in an arbitrary manner.

More specifically, suppose (say) that the support set of the stationary
distribution $\pi$ of an (irreducible positive recurrent aperiodic Harris) Markov chain $(X_k)$ is not bounded from above, so that
$$G(x):=\pi\big((x,\infty)\big)>0$$
for all real $x$. Let then
$$Y_k:=f(X_k),$$
where
$$f(x):=\int_0^x\frac{du}{G(u)}$$
for real $x$, with $\int_0^x:=-\int_x^0$ for real $x<0$. Then $(Y_k)$ is an (irreducible positive recurrent aperiodic Harris) Markov chain with stationary
distribution $\pi_f:=\pi f^{-1}$, the [pushforward](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushforward_measure) of $\pi$ under the map $f$. Moreover,
\begin{align}
\int_{[0,\infty)}y\,\pi_f(dy)&=\int_{[0,\infty)}f(x)\,\pi(dx) \\
&=\int_{[0,\infty)}\pi(dx)\,\int_0^x\frac{du}{G(u)} \\ 
&=\int_0^\infty\frac{du}{G(u)}\,\int_{(u,\infty)} \pi(dx) \\ 
&=\int_0^\infty\frac{du}{G(u)}\,G(u)=\infty. 
\end{align}
So, the first moment of $\pi_f$ cannot be finite.

Similarly one can deal with the case when the support set of the stationary
distribution $\pi$ has a finite limit point.

Comment: Thanks -- I was missing some crucial details in my original post. I think my statements only guaranteed irreducibility. I will edit my post to make the question more precise.

Comment: @LaurentLessard : This is still not enough.

Comment: ok -- I realized I don't know what is needed to ensure finite moments, so I modified the question once more.

Comment: Why the downvote for this answer?

Comment: Because you didn't actually answer my question. Will happily upvote once question is answered or addressed.

Comment: @LaurentLessard : Your original question, "How can I bound the moments of $\pi$?", was answered, by showing that the very premise of the question (that is, the existence of $\pi$) is false in general under your conditions. After that, you invalidated that valid answer (which you should never do) by adding conditions guaranteeing the existence of $\pi$. That modified question was answered as well, by showing that even under those expanded conditions, the best bound on the moments is $\infty$. Finally, for all my time and effort to steer you in the right direction, you downvoted the answer?

Comment: My question was about bounding the moments for a _particular_ $\Psi$. As stated in my question, I have an analytic expression for $\Psi$. The issue is that I cannot find $\pi$ in closed form so computing moments directly is not possible, hence the need to find bounds.

The fact that $\pi$ need not always exist, or that moments can sometimes be unbounded is irrelevant. For my particular $\Psi$, the moments do exist and are bounded; I just can't compute them.

I'm sorry my question wasn't clear. I rewrote it twice in an effort to clarify but evidently I failed. I removed your downvote.

Comment: There was no way for me to know your particular $\Psi$ (I was going to ask you about that, but then forgot). In both versions of your question, your approach was to list a number of properties of $\Psi$, which you apparently hoped will be enough. I showed that, in both versions of your question, the lists of properties of $\Psi$ you gave were not enough. This constitutes complete answers to both versions of your question. You if want to ask further questions with your particular $\Psi$ disclosed or with more properties of it listed, then you can do it in a separate post.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115062/discussion-between-laurent-lessard-and-iosif-pinelis).